# Latency issue in iOS SDK Skype + At completion of connection defaul audio feed is mute

Tags: ios, swift, latency, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I am using iOS SDK Skype for Business following are my concerns.

1. **Latency issue** - It takes lots of time to connect the call even at good network also I am keeping video service on demand default connection is only for Audio feeds.
2. After call connected audio feed **default set to muted**, didChangeIsMuted delegate returns true (Mute). User has to manually press the button to unmute it.
3. Latest SDK Demo at url https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-ios-app-sdk-samples/tree/master/BankingAppSwift is **not compiling successfully**. Few resource files are missing (Helper files).

Answer (score 0):

1. The Meeting join only connects to IM and Audio. It does not enable Video by default. You have to explicitly start the video service one the meeting join in complete (Conversation moves to established state).
   For Latency, can you give an estimate.. how long did it take to join the meeting?
2. We will look at this one and reply back.
3. Please use the Helper files from the SDK Zip package. They are not provided by default in the GitHub samples.

Comment: 1. Usual time is 15 - 25  sec to join a meeting.
2. As I said it is on all platform = default is mute.
3. Yes that is what I did - thank you.